# How would you find products that have 50% of their ratings below 3 in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to broaden my SQL skills and try to understand different queries and how to solve them.

Currently I am trying to find all the products that have over 50% of reviews rating the product less than a 3.

This what I currently have:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.P_NUM,
PRODUCT.P_DES,
AVG(REVIEW.RATE) AS average
FROM PRODUCT INNER JOIN REVIEW
ON PRODUCT.P_NUM = REVIEW.P_NUM
GROUP BY P_DES
HAVING (COUNT(REVIEW.RATE*0.5) > (AVG(REVIEW.RATE) < 3))
```

Are there any pointers for where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Its always good practice to include sample test data and expected result for someone to help you. You query will not work because all columns expect that are in group by clause(P_DES) should have aggregate function applied to it. So either product should be removed or product should also be aggregated

Comment: suggestion: put the clause "COUNT(REVIEW.RATE*0.5)" into your select query to see what value you get. Look at each row, and compare the value of that to your average review rate. Does it make sense? does "COUNT(REVIEW.RATE*0.5)" calculate the percentage of anything? start with writing a query which gets the % of product reviews by rating, and see if you can go from there.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HAVING (SUM(IF(REVIEW.RATE<3,1,0)) > (COUNT(REVIEW.RATE)/2))`, i.e. "the number of ratings that are less than three is more than half of the total number of reviews"?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
select *
from from PRODUCT as p
inner join
(
    select P_NUM, avg(RATE)
    from REVIEW
    group by P_NUM
    having sum(if(RATE < 3, 1, 0)) > count(*) * 0.5
) as r
on p.P_NUM = r.P_NUM
```

so, inner query find all products by summing number of product with rate<3

outer query just find products

this way you avoid groupping by varchar field (p_des)

`if` function is mysql extension to ansi compliant `case`, so it can be replaced with `CASE WHEN RATE < 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE` for other rdms

Comment: Moved it to a solution for access to formatting a full example!  I love CASE, ANSI join and derived table!

Comment: Sybase and SQL Server have an ANSI switch you can turn on, to enforce portability!  I flash on Cognos config files describing the SQL capabilities of each RDBMS -- I had to make one for Borland Interbase starting with one for Teradata!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer 'CASE' over 'if', which I believe is more portable, ANSI. CASE has two forms, one value for value, one value for boolean condition, is a great place to hang comments, too.

```
select *
 from PRODUCT p
  join (
    select
      P_NUM,
      avg(RATE) avg
     from REVIEW
     group by P_NUM
     having sum( CASE WHEN RATE < 3 THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                  END ) > ( count(*) * 0.5 )
    ) as r
   on p.P_NUM = r.P_NUM
```

Answer (score 0):

This conditional aggregation expression:

```
avg(case when rate < 3 then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
```

returns the ratio of the reviews under 3 for each product.
So this query:

```
select p_num
from review
group by p_num
having avg(case when rate < 3 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) > 0.5
```

returns all the `p_num`s that you want.
Use it with the operator `IN` to return each product's details.

```
select p.*
from product p
where p.p_num in (
  select p_num
  from review
  group by p_num
  having avg(case when rate < 3 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) > 0.5
)
```

If you also need the average rating for the product you need a join of `product` to the query:

```
select p.*, t.avg_rating
from product p 
inner join (
  select p_num, avg(rate) avg_rating
  from review
  group by p_num
  having avg(case when rate < 3 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) > 0.5
) t on t.p_num = p.p_num
```